# Add Annotations Generally

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've been trying to add annotations to the mapView generally and having trouble doing so. When I mean generally I mean not specific declaring them. I've looked a lot of programs, and when they want to add more than one annotation they specifically declare them like, Annotation1 =, Annotation 2 =. How do you create a bunch of them without specifying how many there are. Like if I'm trying to add a certain amount of them to the map based on the length of my array of Strings, and the contents inside. Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you don't want to hardcode x lines based on the length of your items. Does this solve your problem?

```
import MapKit

struct Annotation {
    let title: String
    let latitude: CLLocationDegrees
    let longitude: CLLocationDegrees
}

let map = MKMapView()
let array = [Annotation(title: "Peru", latitude: -723232, longitude: 1242424), Annotation(title: "London", latitude: 2942924, longitude: 2424)]

array.forEach({
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.title = $0.title
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: $0.latitude, longitude: $0.longitude)
    map.addAnnotation(annotation)
})
```